# Creating a column by addition of two adjacent rows with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, merge, pandas-groupby, shift

Create column E that fills column C. If D is <10, then it fill C of earlier row and current row.

This is my Input DataSet:

```
I,A,B,C,D
1,P,100+,L,15
2,P,100+,M,9
3,P,100+,N,15
4,P,100+,O,15
5,Q,100+,L,2
6,Q,100+,M,15
7,Q,100+,N,3
8,Q,100+,O,15
```

I tried using some for loops. However, i think we can use shift or append functions to complete this. However, i am getting value errors using the shift function.

Desired Output:

```
I,A,B,C,D,E
1,P,100+,L,15,L
2,P,100+,M,9,M+N
3,P,100+,N,15,M+N
4,P,100+,O,15,O
5,Q,100+,L,2,L+O
6,Q,100+,M,15,M+N
7,Q,100+,N,3,M+N
8,Q,100+,O,15,L+O
```

I am working out the column E given in desired output table above.

Comment: Is output correct? Last 4 values?

Comment: Yes. Here we are trying to merge L with O AND M with N.

Comment: But what is logic? Can you explain more? Because 5, and 8 rows is not next/previous.

Comment: I apologize. If D, L/M/N/O are of different categories. There are given in a sequence. However, I need to merge L with O. In this Case, I had sorted the data in the required sequence of merging and solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `np.where` and `pd.shift`

```
##will populate C values index+1 where the condition is True 
df['E'] = np.where( df['D'] < 10,df.loc[df.index + 1,'C'] , df['C'])
##Appending the values of C and E
df['E'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.C + '+' + x.E if x.C != x.E else x.C, axis=1)
df['F'] = df['E'].shift(1)
##Copying the values at index+1 position where the condition is True
df['E'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.F if '+' in str(x.F) else x.E, axis=1)

df.drop('F', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

**Output**

```
   I  A     B  C   D    E
0  1  P  100+  L  15    L
1  2  P  100+  M   9  M+N
2  3  P  100+  N  15  M+N
3  4  P  100+  O  15    O
4  5  Q  100+  L   2  L+M
5  6  Q  100+  M  15  L+M
6  7  Q  100+  N   3  N+O
7  8  Q  100+  O  15  N+O
```

Answer (score 1):

Idea is create helper groups by replace values of index by mask with [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and forward filling only one missing value, then set new column by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and `join`:

```
m = df['D'].lt(10)
g = df.index.to_series().where(m).ffill(limit=1)
df['E'] = np.where(g.notna(), df['C'].groupby(g.fillna(-1)).transform('+'.join), df['C'])
print (df)
   I  A     B  C   D    E
0  1  P  100+  L  15    L
1  2  P  100+  M   9  M+N
2  3  P  100+  N  15  M+N
3  4  P  100+  O  15    O
4  5  Q  100+  L   2  L+M
5  6  Q  100+  M  15  L+M
6  7  Q  100+  N   3  N+O
7  8  Q  100+  O  15  N+O
```